# Textarea having always window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure how to do this. II'm currently using Bootstrap's textarea, along with its container. I don't know how to make it so that the textarea extends to the bottom of the screen, which automatically increase/decrease depending on the window height. I've tried:

```
#form-control {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

But nothing seems to change. Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Edit:

This is my html file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="note"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put height property on the element like the code below.

```
#form-control {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
}
```

If it doesn't work, try !important. If it doesn't work either, try setting rows in markup and set line-height on CSS.

```
<textarea rows="4">
```

Comment: Ah that works! But the thing is, I want the `container` div around it so that I can make the textarea be only be inside that `div`, and at the bottom of the screen I can put 1-2 more row of information. I'll keep playing around with it

Comment: In that case, you can set fixed heigth on container and set 100% to #form-conrol's height property. Don't forget to set position:fixed to the container instead.

Answer (score 1):

`.form-control` should be a CSS class for bootstrap.

Are you using `<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>`? If so, your css rule is using `#`, which corresponds to an element ID, not a class. Change your CSS to this:

```
.form-control {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Right, the `.` made it work, but I wanted to make the container div wrap is so I can position the textare in the middle of the screen. Is that possible? This is because I want to leave some white space at the bottom of the screen for some extra text/functions

Comment: Use `position: absolute` instead, and add `position:relative` to the `.container` div.

Comment: I managed to make it work, but it looks different comparing to everything here haha :S

Comment: @Rohinder awesome to hear! in that case, you should submit your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
Actually you have used (id) #form-control, which should be (class) .form-control
I've used your code, just added width 100%
Now it'll take height and width of screen.

```css
.form-control {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `height` property to set it to a certain height.

You can do something like this:

```
#form-control {
position:fixed;
height: 200px;
}
```

or

```
#form-control {
position:fixed;
height: 50%;
}
```

Just as a few examples.

I would suggest that you check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) W3 Schools page on the height css property... If you read the page you can see how else you can size it.

On that page there is also a link to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_height&preval=200px) demo which I suggest you try to see what the different "settings" for lack of better word do.

Also make sure that the opening `<textarea>` tag calls the [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)... so it should look something like this `<textarea id="form-control">`.

Good Luck